# Remove last 2 digits from the array members if the number is more than 2 digit

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have an array that consists of multiple elements so what I want to do is remove the last two digits from the array element if the array element consists of 3 or 4 digits then remove the last two digits from it. and if the  element is 1 or 2 digits then it will remain the same.

```
var test =[ 2, 45,567, 3, 6754];
```

Then the output that I need is :

```
[ 2, 45, 5, 3, 67];
```

I have tried this

```
test.forEach(function(element, index) {    test[index] = element.slice(1, -2); });
```

But this will remove the single digits element to blank

Comment: why isnt 567 become 5

Comment: Yes it is 5 i have edited it

Comment: try to use map instead of forEach it might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution you wrote would not work at all, because u try to slice values with type number.

Try this:

```
test.forEach(function(element, index) {    test[index] = String(element).length > 2 ? +String(element).slice(0, -2) : test[index]});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could divide the value by 100 and take the integer value, if necessary.

```js
const
    data = [2, 45, 567, 3, 6754],
    result = data.map(v => v >= 100 ? Math.floor(v / 100) : v);

console.log(result);
```